# Curator TreeCache eventual consistency

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

When using Curator TreeCache. I understand that there is no guarantee for cache state to stay synchronous with the leader and that create/update/delete events can be missed ([Zookeeper missed events on successive changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806413/zookeeper-missed-events-on-successive-changes)).
From what I understand however - TreeCache will be eventually consistent. 
Question is: Is there any maximum (guaranteed) time defined in which the change in ZK node gets propagated to the TreeCache instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't a maximum time. Note: this has nothing to do with TreeCache it's merely how ZooKeeper works. Internally, all write operations go through the current leader node in your ZK ensemble. The "follower" nodes eventually synchronize with the leader's database. In practice, this will be a matter of seconds at the most but, of course, it depends entirely on the size of your database, your network, the number of operations in flight, etc.

Update: note that you configure your ZK instances with `syncLimit` which specifies the maximum db sync for your ensemble. ZooKeeper will timeout when syncLimit is exceeded. See here: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html

Comment: So the follower will fail if it exceeds syncLiimit? In this case it is ok to say that no follower can get more then syncLimit behind. Isn't this a guarantee?
Obviously I understand that additional time is required to send data from Follower to TreeCache or to reconnect to another follower if the one that client is connected to fails.

Comment: If a sync exceeds syncLimit the instance will fail and will be dropped from the ensemble.